# Having difficult time finding the font used in this logo

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to find the font used in "lasting definition" title of the following image. My guesses so far are Cookie, Great Vibes, and Ruthie but none of them is an exact match.

[image: Logo]

Cookie:
[image: Cookie]

Great Vibes:
[image: Great Vibes]

Ruthie:
[image: Ruthie]

Comment: A great tool you could use for this is Whatthefont (google it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the font. It is called [Olympic Branding](http://www.dafont.com/olympic-branding.font).

[image: Olympic Branding Preview]

Comment: Can you comment as to how you found it? One of the online search tools, or just experience?

Comment: It turned out that a friend of mine knew the font and used it before. I wish there was a font search engine though.

Comment: well there are plenty of font search engines based off of images, they're just not very good. eg [what the font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), [font-squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator)